# What is the correct way to return an array in a function? Cannot read property of undefined\n

Tags: javascript

What is the correct way to return an array in a function? I want to get achievements[n].Completedachievs.Id, but it's not working.

I get an error message in this line:

```
var currentid = achievements[n].Completedachievs.Id.toString();
```

> "Error": {
> "Error": "JavascriptException",
> "Message": "JavascriptException",
> "StackTrace": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Completedachievs' of undefined\n    at handlers.CheckingAchievements
> }

```
function Achievements(achievs)
{
    var achieverror = false;
    var completedachievs = [];

    for (var i = 0; i <= achievs.length - 1; i++)
    {
        // ...
        for (var j = 0; j <= Statistics.length - 1; j++)
        {
            // ...
            const myachiev = {Id:achievs[i].Id, Gold:achievs[i].Gold, Silver:achievs[i].Silver, Wood:achievs[i].Wood};
            completedachievs.push(myachiev);
        }
    }
    return { AchievError: achieverror, Completedachievs: completedachievs };
}

handlers.CheckingAchievements = function (args, context)
{
    // ...
    var achievements = Achievements(checkallachievs);
    for (var n = 0; n <= achievements.Completedachievs.length - 1; n++)
    {
        var currentid = achievements[n].Completedachievs.Id.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're returning an *object* with `AchievError` and `Completedachievs` properties. If you want to use the array that the latter property contains, use `achievements.Completedachievs[n]`, not `achievements[n]`.

Comment: Try to analyse the error message. It says it all. Debug why `achievements[n]` is `undefined` by stepping through the code. If you still cannot find the cause, make sure we can run your code with defined data and see it reproduce the error.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanx, it works now.